# How to only expand the group of the 'SelectedItem' in a WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping, expander

I only want to expand the group of the SelectedItem of the datagrid, all other  expanders will be collapsed.
The 'SelectedItem' is selected from codebehind.
The Item is of type 'Vault_Item' and is bind to Property 'RawMaterialItem'
The used event is '.SelectionChanged':

```
Private Sub Dgv_RawMaterials_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles Dgv_RawMaterials.SelectionChanged
  If Dgv_RawMaterials.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim SelectedMaterialItem As Vault_Item = DirectCast(Dgv_RawMaterials.SelectedItem, Vault_Item)
    _vm.RawMaterialItem = SelectedMaterialItem
    'What to do next?....
  End If
End Sub
```

This is my GroupStyle:

```
  <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">

  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="Group_HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <Expander  IsExpanded="False" Padding="5,2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFD5DCE8">
              <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text=" ("  FontWeight="DemiBold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"  Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text=" "  FontWeight="DemiBold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="Items"  FontWeight="DemiBold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text=")" FontWeight="DemiBold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
              </Expander.Header>
              <Expander.Content>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
              </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

This is my datagrid:

```
<TabItem x:Name="TabItem_RawMaterials" Header="Raw Materials">
            <DataGrid x:Name="Dgv_RawMaterials" Style="{DynamicResource DgvStyle}" HeadersVisibility="None">
              <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource Group_HeaderStyle}">
                  <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
              </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Vault_Description}" Header="Description" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="*" />
              </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
      </TabItem>
```

[This is the result I want achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk1Zh.png)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Create a Boolean property as IsExpanded inside the SelectedMaterialItem, bind the property in xaml inside your Expander's GroupHeaderStyle with the Expander's IsExpanded propety and simply set the property to true of the SelectedItem of the grid every time the selection changes.

Comment: Raviraj, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: Make sure that the IsExpaded property has a RelativeSource mentioned with the FindAncestor mode and mention the x:Type as DataGrid. The Mode should be TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger on PropertyChanged. It is working at my end.

Comment: What I am doing wrong?
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: You must be having the SelectedItem property in your viewmodel right? RawMaterialItem? make Path="RawMaterialItem.IsExpanded"

Comment: I get the following error code:
Additional information: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: xaml:
                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                  Path={Binding RawMaterialItem.IsExpanded},
                  Mode=TwoWay, 
                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          Padding="5,2" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          Background="#FFD5DCE8">

Comment: Please remove "Binding" from the Path. 
It should look like Path=RawMaterialItem.IsExpanded and the rest as it is.

Comment: No errors anymore but the group expander is still not expanded.
What do you need to know?

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/

Comment: This link is about 'RowDetails' this has no secrets for me anymore.
I am now struggling with grouping.
But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is a new solution to your question, please change other things as per your requirements:

```
<DataGridColumn>
<DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Header="{Binding SomeText}">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
        </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
```